# How do I minimalise distortion on fluid images, and how do I also add a Gaussian Blur to that image?

Tags: image, gaussian, distortion, fluid-images

i have a website where I have 2 users

Problem a. User A doesn't add a banner image. So we have to enlarger their profile image. When enlarging it I am getting distorted.

Problem b. How do I add a Gaussian blur

Problem c. How do I then make that image fluid

Codeigniter PHP

Hope you can help

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. It would help if you would indicate what the technology/framework is. Please edit the post (code is welcome) and add appropriate tags to tell us if this is in php, asp.net, ruby-on-rails or something else.

Comment: My apologies - framework codeigniter PHP